# Heat map in python

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I have three variables that I need to plot for sales transactions, `timestamp` (of the sale), `price`, and `zip_code`. Is there a python or javascript library where I could plot a heat map with these variables? Perhaps something similar to HighCharts, but with geographical plotting.

Comment: May the answer use libraries like GnuPlot or do you want it to be pure Python/JS?

Comment: Anything, whatever would be easiest to implement

Answer (score 2):

[Heatmap.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) is a great clientside library for it.

Example with [Google Maps](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/demo/maps_heatmap_layer/gmaps.php)

Example with [Open Layers](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/demo/maps_heatmap_layer/openlayers.php)

Comment: Interesting. Is there any way to view the actual data on the map?

Answer (score 1):

[Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) is a great Python plotting library.  It has geographical plotting abilities using the basemap toolkit.  However, I don't think it has information on zip code boundaries, so you would have to get ZIP code shapefiles from somewhere.  Googling suggests they may be available from the US Census website.

I'm not aware of any Python plotting toolkit that supports ZIP code-based mapping out of the box.  What matplotlib with basemap allows you to do is plot ordinary markers (dots, shapes, etc.) onto a map.  It would be easy, for instance, to plot a map with colored dots (with colors "heatmapped" corresponding to transaction price, say) across a map of the USA.  It seems like the hard part of what you want is getting map data that includes information about ZIP code boundaries.  I'm pretty sure you could get matplotlib to work, but it could take some setup work to get that ZIP code information hooked up in the right way.

Comment: If you are going the Python way, colormaps are in module `matplotlib.pyplot`, and a good recipe is here: http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps . Pro: greater control; Con: much lower level / manual work than Heatmap.js, it seems.

Comment: This looks like it definitely would not work for graphing worldwide geographical data by zipcode.

Comment: There isn't really such a thing as "worldwide geographical data by zipcode".  ZIP codes are peculiar to the US postal service and only cover the US.  Each country has its own system of postal codes.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

First, download the US Census Bureau shapefile
Second, plot the shapes in matplotlib

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/CloudCray/8711607) on how to download zip code shapefiles and how to use the files to draw a map. It also shows you how to vary the color of individual zipcodes.

You would scale the datapoints you're looking for, then either use the grayscale percentages or RGB tuple to vary the color by zip code.